# jquery .show shows only at the end

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, webmethod

I want to display a loading div before an ajax command that executes a webmethod, closing at the end of the command. 
The div appears only at the end of the implementation of ajax command.

The following code block.

```
$("#dvUpProgress1").show();
$.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "producao.aspx/GravarListaSalvar",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (obj) { }
        });
```

in the code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GravarListaSalvar(string IdAutorizacaoProducaoGarantiaQualidade, string IdEtapa, string IdSubEtapa, string IdUsuarioLogado, string NomeCampo, string NomeAmigavel, string Resposta, string IdCampo)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You have set your POST request to be synchronous, via the `async: false`.  Browsers don't render things until the script is finished running - which only happens AFTER your post has finished.

Comment: @entropic is right. He should post it as the answer...

Comment: @LcSalazar Was planning to once I had more time to write up a little more.  But thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your POST request to be synchronous, via `async: false`. Browsers don't render things until the script is finished running - which only happens AFTER your post has finished.

If you want the progress bar to show up, you need to implement your call asynchronously, so the browser can render the the loading div while the server is processing the request.  Anything done after the call in your current routine, you would then move to the `success` function you have created.  Your javascript should be updated like so:

```js
$("#dvUpProgress1").show();
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "producao.aspx/GravarListaSalvar",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (obj) {
        // Here is where the rest of your code should go 
    }
});
```

You'll notice that I changed `async` to `true`, which tells the browser to process the call asynchronously, freeing up the browser to render the progress bar.

If you absolutely MUST make the call synchronously, you could always implement `setTimeout` by doing something like this

```
$("#dvUpProgress1").show();
setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "producao.aspx/GravarListaSalvar",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (obj) {
            // Here is where the rest of your code should go 
        }
    });
}, 100);
```

.. but then you're really losing all the benefit of the asynchronous processing that AJAX was developed to do (after all, AJAX stands for Asynchronous JS and XML).  So I **really, really** would advise **AGAINST** doing synchronous calls.

Comment: Earlier async was false, but was not working. I used the setTimeout too, but not with the ajax parameter. I will test the setTimeout this way. Thanks.

Comment: Just to reiterate, the async parameter really should be true.  You WANT to run the call asynchronously, not the other way around.

Comment: I tried with async true and false in the way you instructed and the div appears only at the end of processing. Thanks anyway. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a jsfiddle?

Comment: After several attempts, I found that does not work in Chrome, Firefox works correctly. Any suggestions to work in both browsers?